# Driving a 12V door strike from 3V3 BeagleBone?

Tags: transistors, linux, beagleboard

I'm trying to control a [12V electronic door strike lock](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Door-NC-NO-Access-Control-Electric-Strike-Monitoring-/160354433212?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2555de78bc#ht_5570wt_1398) from my 3V3 BeagleBone.

Here's a diagram of my circuit:

[image: Simple Circuit Diagram]

My circuit probably needs a NPN transisor of some sort, but I'm not sure which one would work. Also, because the strike lock is a solenoid, do I need any diodes/other protection in my circuit to prevent over-voltage/other bad things?

Thanks. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what your power source for the Beaglebone is, but I'd probably use a separate supply for the solenoid. The BB has/needs information level power, not do-mechanical-things power. Why force that through it? Plus, you may be able to avoid needing the step up circuit. Nor does the solenoid need highly regulated power at a precise tolerance. Yes, a reverse connected protection diode across the solenoid to deal with the jolt when power is removed and its magnetic field collapses is always a Good Idea. (Better qualified persons will answer your which transistor question.)

Comment: Do you have 12V available? GPI01 via 1k resistor to transistor base. Emitter to ground. collector to strike terminal 1 (either). 12V+ to strike terminal 2. 1N400x diode across strike coil - Cathode = line side to =!2V. Transistor BC337-40. Many others work but if you have none that's as good as most. Available Digikey and w=elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to connect the lock on the collector side of the transistor; common collector like you've drawn doesn't work.

[image]

The [BC337-40](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC817_BC817W_BC337.pdf) suggested by Russell is a good choice; it has a high \$H_{FE}\$, and can draw up to 500 mA.

Your power supply needs some attention. You need 12 V at 250 mA, that's 3 W. If you have a boost converter with 85 % efficiency this will need more than 1 A from the BB, and that's probably more than it can supply. Definitely too much if you're powering the board from USB. I would power the lock from a 12 V/1 A wall wart.

Comment: I strongly recommend wiring the diode directly across the lock's terminals rather than at the transistor circuit board (which I assume will be at or very near the BeagleBone board).